# Svn: error while loading shared libraries: libserf-1.so.0

Tags: svn, ubuntu-10.10

I want to upgrade from svn 1.6 to 1.7 on my Ubuntu 10

I followed a few links over the internet to add some repositories such as https://askubuntu.com/questions/65468/where-can-i-find-a-subversion-1-7-binary and after trying some messy things, but I landed up getting stuck with this error whenever i type svn on the command line.

> Svn: error while loading shared libraries: libserf-1.so.0 cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

No matter how many times i remove and reinstall subversion and libserf1, nothing changes. The only thing i suspect is that i get this error message

> WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!   libserf1
>   libsvn1 subversion

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that there is something to do with the repository dominik-stadler in the error message below.

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libserf1 libsvn1 subversion
Authentication warning overridden.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dominik-stadler/subversion-1.7/ubuntu/ lucid/main libserf1 1.0.0-2ubuntu0~ppa3 [42.6kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/svn/ppa/ubuntu/ lucid/main libsvn1 1.7.9-0svn1~lucid+svn1 [1,095kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/svn/ppa/ubuntu/ lucid/main subversion 1.7.9-0svn1~lucid+svn1 [1,292kB]
```

So i went to first purged subversion & libserf1 i.e `sudo apt-get purge subversion` and `sudo apt-get purge libserf1` , then went to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and removed the following files

> dominik-stadler-subversion-1.7-lucid.list
>
> dominik-stadler-subversion-1.7-lucid.list.save

and later a simple `sudo apt-get install subversion` installed everything perfectly.

I have no clue why/how this works, but thought i'd just document this here for someone else to benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but did not want to reinstall subversion as noted above. I was able to create a sym link in /usr/lib to the existing .so file and that seems to have worked. I was able to do a checkout that gave me the error above before this:

Ubuntu 12.04
SVN 1.7, from http://ppa.launchpad.net/dominik-stadler

cd /usr/lib

Original Listing:
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       194514 Nov  1 14:53 libserf-1.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           18 Nov  1 14:53 libserf-1.so -> libserf-1.so.1.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           18 Nov  1 14:53 libserf-1.so.1 -> libserf-1.so.1.3.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       110056 Nov  1 14:53 libserf-1.so.1.3.0

Command: **sudo ln -s libserf-1.so.1.3.0 libserf-1.so.0**

Updated Listing:
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       194514 Nov  1 14:53 libserf-1.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           18 Nov  1 14:53 libserf-1.so -> libserf-1.so.1.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           18 Dec 21 18:19 **libserf-1.so.0 -> libserf-1.so.1.3.0**
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           18 Nov  1 14:53 libserf-1.so.1 -> libserf-1.so.1.3.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       110056 Nov  1 14:53 libserf-1.so.1.3.0